# Ionic Router: Subpage is only loaded after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router

I have a list page, where all games from my games.json file are displayed.

This is what that looks like in GameListPage.tsx:

```
<IonList>
  {gamesJson.map((game) => (
    <IonItem
      routerLink={
        game.software_used ?
          /games/id/${game.steam_appid}` : '/games'
      }
      key={game.steam_appid}
    >
      <IonThumbnail slot="start">
        <img alt={game.name} src={game.header_image} />
      </IonThumbnail>
      <IonLabel>
        <h2>{game.name}</h2>
        <p>{game.developer}</p>
      </IonLabel>
    </IonItem>
  ))}
</IonList>
```

When you click on the item, you are redirected to the game details page. However, you are only redirected after refreshing the page.

This is what my `IonReactRouter` looks like in App.tsx:

```
<IonReactRouter>
  <IonTabs>
    <IonRouterOutlet>
      <Route exact path="/games">
        <GameListPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/games/id/:id">
        <GameDetailsPage />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/software">
        <SoftwareListPage />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Redirect to="/games" />
      </Route>
    </IonRouterOutlet>
    <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
      <IonTabButton tab="games" href="/games">
        <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={triangle} />
        <IonLabel>Games</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
      <IonTabButton tab="software" href="/software">
        <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={ellipse} />
        <IonLabel>Software</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
    </IonTabBar>
  </IonTabs>
</IonReactRouter>
```

How can I fix this issue so that the page is instantly loaded after clicking on the item in the list?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you need to use `react-router-dom` [npm library](https://reactrouter.com/en/main)
2. then you need to use `<Link>` component with the (to) attribute `<Link to={_link distination_}>{children}</Link>`

for example, it will be like this (indeed after you set your routers well)

```js
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
function MyComponent({game}){


return 

  <IonList>
    {gamesJson.map((game) => {
      const href = game.software_used ?`/games/id/${game.steam_appid}` : '/games'
  
      return 
       <Link to={href} key={game.steam_appid}>
          <IonItem>
             <IonThumbnail slot="start">
                 <img alt={game.name} src={game.header_image}/>
             </IonThumbnail>
             <IonLabel>
                 <h2>{game.name}</h2>
                 <p>{game.developer}</p>
             </IonLabel>
         </IonItem>      
      </Link>
  })}
                        
                   
</IonList>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This way you will use the react routing and the page will not rerender.

Comment: Just FYI, [IonReactRouter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation) is a wrapper around React-Router. OP is already using RRD `Link` and `Route` components.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I believe I once solved a similar issue by rendering the routes into the `Switch` component exported from `react-router-dom`. The `IonContent` component may or may not be needed in your case, but including it here as an example:

```
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  IonContent,
  IonRouterOutlet,
  IonIcon,
  IonLabel,
  IonTabs,
  IonTabBar,
  IonTabButton,
  setupIonicReact,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { IonReactRouter } from "@ionic/react-router";
```

```
<IonReactRouter>
  <IonTabs>
    <IonRouterOutlet>
      <IonContent>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/games/id/:id" component={GameDetailsPage}  />
          <Route path="/games" component={GameListPage} />
          <Route path="/software" component={SoftwareListPage} />
          <Redirect to="/games" />
        </Switch>
      </IonContent>
    </IonRouterOutlet>
    <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
      <IonTabButton tab="games" href="/games">
        <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={triangle} />
        <IonLabel>Games</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
      <IonTabButton tab="software" href="/software">
        <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={ellipse} />
        <IonLabel>Software</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
    </IonTabBar>
  </IonTabs>
</IonReactRouter>
```